# R Travis OSX - clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

Tags: r, macos, travis-ci

I'm using Travis CI to test my package on Linux and Mac. One of the packages in the `Suggests:` needs openMP. Installing this package on Travis-Linux works fine but not on Travis-Mac.

See the [error](https://travis-ci.org/privefl/bigstatsr/jobs/269457950#L1069).

I've tried to use

```
compiler:
  - gcc
```

in my `.travis.yml` file, but it didn't solved this issue.

Any idea?

**Edit:**
Based on @Jaap's comment, I tried to use

```
before_install:
  - if [ "${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}" == "osx" ]; then brew install llvm; fi
```

in my `.travis.yml` file, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe the [installation instructions (scroll to the end for instructions regarding OpenMP)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of the **data.table**-package can help.

Comment: @Jaap Thanks for pointing me to that. Please see my edit.

Comment: @F.Privé I'm running into this problem also. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @duckmayr Not sure. I think I didn't do anything. Sometimes you have these kinds of issues with Travis/AppVeyor and they just disappear the next day.

Comment: @F.Privé Thanks for the response. If you run into the issue in the future, it could help you to know that in my case, as it turns out, I had to use a trick used by `RcppArmadillo` to dynamically set `-fopenmp` as detailed in [this guide](https://ankargren.github.io/avoiding-openmp-problems-in-rcpparmadillo-dependent-packages-on-os-x).

Answer (score 0):

The Travis mac environment incorrectly states that it supports OpenMP, by setting `SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS` and `SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS`. OpenMP on mac is generally a disaster. You could try un-setting these environment variables (I've never tried this), or use a configure script. There is a m4 macro in the R sources which detects openmp, which you can re-use with appropriate attribution to the R Core Team. I do this in my package `icd`.